# Height of the Binary search tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
public static int getHeight(Node root){
    if(root == null){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
      int left = getHeight(root.left);
        int right = getHeight(root.right);

        return 1+ Math.max(left, right);
    }
```

Hii I am using this method to calculate the height of the binary search tree buy it returns 1+value of the actual height of the binary tree(E.g. If the height is 3 this method is returning 4). Anyone tell me what's  wrong with this code.

Comment: If there is only one node, what is the expected height? 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If root is null than return -1, instead of 1,i.e change line

```
if(root == null){
        return 0;
 }
```

to

```
if(root == null){
        return -1;
 }
```